Referencing Custom Tab created using ExcelDna.AddIn in manifest.xml office js add on
If I've created a custom tab using ExcelDna.AddIn, CustomRibbon.xml, how do I deploy an officejs add on, using manifest.xml, so that officejs addon is placed inside that custom tab created from ExcelDna.AddIn?
Essentially this is like combining both ExcelDna.AddIn and officejs manifest.xml addon approaches. The reason is not important. I need help getting this to work.
If the id of the tab, in CustomRibbon.xml is myTab, then I referneced it inside manifest.xml as follows:
`<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
  <CustomTab id="myTab">
...
</>`

However, it is not working. How do I go about this?
Follow up, if the id in CustomRibbon.xml is mentioned using 'idQ' attribute, and from my research manifest.xml does not support idQ, how do i make it point to that tab with idQ value?
idQ in CustomRibbon.xml:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idQ="OurTab">
        <group idQ="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
        </group>
      </tab>
....
</>`

Please help, thanks!
I want to correctly reference the tab (or its id) inside manifest.xml of officejs addon, so i can load the add on into the custom tab created using CustomRibbon.xml ExcelDna.AddIn approach.
